Set legend position and tooltip text in ggplotly()
In this plot I want to have in my tooltip text Date,Total_Value, Attribute Name and Percentage in separate lines and I see nothing. Also my legend moved from bottom to the right which i do not want.
data_counts<-structure(list(Date = c("December - 2023", "December - 2023", 
"December - 2023", "February - 2024", "February - 2024", "February - 2024", 
"January - 2024", "January - 2024", "January - 2024", "March - 2024", 
"March - 2024", "March - 2024"), `Attribute Name` = c("patients_have_both", 
"patients_have_ev_without_sg", "patients_have_sg_without_ev", 
"patients_have_both", "patients_have_ev_without_sg", "patients_have_sg_without_ev", 
"patients_have_both", "patients_have_ev_without_sg", "patients_have_sg_without_ev", 
"patients_have_both", "patients_have_ev_without_sg", "patients_have_sg_without_ev"
), Total_Value = c(152, 28, 821, 163, 27, 899, 157, 27, 854, 
169, 27, 953), percentage = c(0.151848151848152, 0.027972027972028, 
0.82017982017982, 0.149678604224059, 0.0247933884297521, 0.825528007346189, 
0.151252408477842, 0.0260115606936416, 0.822736030828516, 0.147084421235857, 
0.0234986945169713, 0.829416884247171)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), groups = structure(list(
    Date = c("December - 2023", "February - 2024", "January - 2024", 
    "March - 2024"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))



p<-ggplot(data_counts, aes(x = Date, y = Total_Value, fill = `Attribute Name`),
              text = paste0(Total_Value, " (", scales::percent(percentage), ")")
              ) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.3) +
      labs(x = "Month of Flatiron Data Cutoff", y = "Patient Counts", title = "ADC Uptake over time among advanced UC") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue", "darkblue", "maroon")) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        legend.position = "bottom"  # Position the legend at the bottom
      )
    ggplotly(p,tooltip = "text")


You need to set the legend position inside the ggplotly() function. Like this:
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(data_counts, 
            aes(x = Date, y = Total_Value, fill = `Attribute Name`,
                text = paste("Date:", Date,
                             "\nTotal Value:", Total_Value, " (", scales::percent(percentage), ")",
                             "\nName:", `Attribute Name`))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.3) +
  labs(x = "Month of Flatiron Data Cutoff", 
       y = "Patient Counts", 
       title = "ADC Uptake over time among advanced UC") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue", "darkblue", "maroon")) +
  theme_minimal()

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>%
  layout(legend = list(x = 0, 
                       y = -0.2,
                       xanchor = "left",
                       yanchor = "bottom",
                       orientation = "h"))

Screencap of result:

